# How to find variable values that make an expression divergent or undefined?

Tags: equation-solving

How can I find all the values of a variable at which a given expression diverges or becomes undefined?

Example:

```
expr=1/(1-x^2);
```

Desired result:

```
(* {1,-1} or {{x->1},{x->-1}} *)
```

Example:

```
expr=x/x
```

Desired result:

```
(* 0  or {0}  or {{x->0}} *)
```

EDIT: Some users pointed out I can just find when the Denominator[expr]==0, but that doesn't work for some functions like:

```
expr=Exp[1/x]
```

Comment: How about `Solve[0 == 1/expr, x]`. That will at least get you the ones where it diverges.

Comment: @march  That doesn't work for more complicated stuff like expr=Exp[1/x]

Answer (score 3):

**Update 1**

The following function works for all the cases mentioned so far except for the trivial x/x case.

```
 findPoles[expr_] := Module[{pos, npos},
 (*find position of all Power in the fullform of the function*)
 pos = Position[FullForm[expr], Power];
 (*drop the last 0 to get the position of the actual power
 expression*)
 npos = Drop[pos[[#]], -1] & /@ Range[Length[pos]];
 (*extract those position, 
 find their denominators and delete those which have none. 
 Lastly Solve for the poles*)
 Solve[DeleteCases[Denominator[Extract[FullForm[expr], npos]], 1] == 
    0, x]]
```

Testing the function

```
 expr[1] = 1/(1 - x^2);
 expr[2] = Exp[1/x];
 Table[findPoles[expr[i]], {i, 2}]
 (*{{{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}}, {{x -> 0}}}*)
```

---

Using the `Denominator` command and then `Solve`

```
findDiv[exp_] := 
Which[exp === 1, {{x -> 0}}, True, Solve[Denominator[exp] == 0, x]]

expr = 1/(1 - x^2);
findDiv[expr]
(*{{x\[Rule]-1},{x\[Rule]1}}*)

expr = x/x;
findDiv[expr]
(*{{x\[Rule]0}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks!  But I why did you put it inside a Which[]?  And why do you have it return x->0 if the input expression is identical to 1?

Comment: well that was just to reproduce the desired result for your second example where x/x evaluates to 1

Comment: This doesn't work for more complicated stuff like expr=Exp[1/x]

Comment: @JerryGuern  check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = 1/(1 - x^2);

FunctionDomain[expr, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[expr, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Show "complement" graphically

```
NumberLinePlot[
 expr == 10^6,
 {x, -2, 2},
 AspectRatio -> 1/3,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None, None, None},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting info, but I want what we might call the "compliment of the domain", not the domain.